# Как называются классы атомарных счетчиков в boost и Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, boost

Нужен готовый код реализации класса атомарного счетчика. Имеется ли таковой в boost? Помню, таковой имеется в Qt, но точно не помню как называется, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Там вроде есть atomicInt и atomicInteger, из кого можно счетчик сделать?

Comment: Так они в стандартной библиотеке есть, см <atomic>

Comment: @VTT там вроде только два класса - atomic и atomic_flag. Или Вы функции имели ввиду?

Comment: А чего вам в них не хватает?